# How can prevent a space from being appended to the tab-completed word using Perl's Term::Readline?

Tags: perl, readline

I am using tab completion support of [Term::ReadLine::Gnu](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Term::ReadLine::Gnu) module. Every time I do a tab, I get a space after the completed word.

For example:

If i have a word "complete" as a possible completion. After prompt I pressed tab and I am 
getting it like:

"complete "

where these is a space at the end of the completed word. What I want is:

"complete"

Is there any way to remove that space?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this (untested) in your completion function:

```
my $attribs = $term->Attribs;
$attribs->{completion_suppress_append} = 1;
```

This corresponds to the `rl_completion_suppress_append` variable in GNU readline.

Answer (score -1):

Set `completion_suppress_append` to 1 in a completion function.

See https://github.com/hirooih/perl-trg/issues/22.